# AWS ECS Fargate Splunk Logging

Tags: logging, splunk, aws-fargate

The documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_LogConfiguration.html 
says that the default config does not support Splunk logging for Fargate. 
Does anyone know of a workaround for this? I am looking to send the logs from multiple fargate containers to a central Splunk instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Fargate supports Splunk now

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/aws-fargate-pv1-3-now-supports-the-splunk-log-driver/

Answer (score 0):

It says only awslogs driver is supported for fargate so your logs are being written to Cloudwatch. You can configure an AWS Lambda function to forward those Cloudwatch logs to Splunk, see https://www.splunk.com/blog/2017/02/03/how-to-easily-stream-aws-cloudwatch-logs-to-splunk.html